# can't construct sr25519 Public key from AuthorityId in pallet but it works in outer node? Same function

Tags: pallet, aura

I'm retrieving the list of authorities from aura in the pallet like this:

```
let authorities = pallet_aura::Pallet::<T>::authorities();
```

this should return a `Vec<T::AuthorityId>` which is supposedly the same as `sp_core::sr25519::Public` since `AuthorityId` in Aura is defined like that [here](https://releases.parity.io/substrate-rustdoc/sp_consensus_aura/sr25519/type.AuthorityId.html), so I did the following:

```
authorities.into_iter().map(|id| Public::from_h256(H256::from_slice(id.as_slice())));
```

I'm doing it this way because for some reason in `AuthorityId` I don't have access to any method like `sp_core::sr25519::Public`, (I specifically need the [verify](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_application_crypto/trait.RuntimePublic.html#tymethod.verify) method) which is why in the pallet it throws an error:

```
 no method named `as_slice` found for associated type `<T as pallet_aura::Config>::AuthorityId` in the current scope
```

now, having said that, in outer node if I call the runtime api [`authorities()`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sc_consensus_aura/trait.AuraApi.html#method.authorities) and I try to create sr25519 keys from it, it works:

```
let authorities= client
    .runtime_api()
    .authorities(&block_id)
    .expect("error");
authorities
    .iter()
    .map(|pubkey| Public::from_h256(H256::from_slice(pubkey.as_slice())))
    .collect()
```

- why is this happening, even though its completely the same function, I`m stuck with` AuthorityId` which has literally zero methods? and are there simpler ways to retrieve the Public keys of the current authorities that does not require all this mess?

Ps: I tried importing the trait `use sp_core::ByteArray;` but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/549165727c3b3c14b6f90011085aaebbeff9d7e3/frame/aura/src/lib.rs#LL72-L76C20.

Because it doesn't have a `ByteArray` trait bound, you can't do that.

But it has a `RuntimeAppPublic` trait bound.

You can import `sp_application_crypto::RuntimeAppPublic` and call `to_raw_vec()` on it.

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/549165727c3b3c14b6f90011085aaebbeff9d7e3/primitives/application-crypto/src/traits.rs#L127-L128